# How to add an HTML element after two record zii.widgets.CListView widget Yii

Tags: php, html, css, yii

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'summaryText'=>'',
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

I need an output like

```
__________________________
ID   : 10    ID   : 11
Name : XXX   Name : YYYY
Age  : 15    Age  : 20
Place: abc   Place:xyz
--------------------------
ID   : 12    ID   : 13
Name : aaa   Name : sss
Age  : 24    Age  : 27
Place: vvc   Place:xzss
--------------------------
```

How to change my `_view.php` for this?

This is for voucher printing, so I need to reduce paper cost, that's why I seek this solution.

Comment: This is more of designing. You've to change your `HTML CSS` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML as posted by Mohit Bhansali. But you'll have to add some more CSS first:

```
.view {
    float: left;
    width: 250px; /* or other width */
}
```

Then in your `_view.php` you clear that float on top, for each second item. You can use the predefined `$index` variable:

```
<?php if($index!=0 && $index%2==0): ?>
    <div style="clear:left"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set you design something like this:

```
<div class="view">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('ID')); ?>:</b></th>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('name')); ?>:</b></th>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->name), array('view', 'id'=>$data->name)); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('age')); ?>:</b></th>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->age), array('view', 'id'=>$data->age)); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('place')); ?>:</b></th>
            <td><?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->place), array('view', 'id'=>$data->place)); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Set some CSS:

```
<style>
    table, td, th
    {
        border:1px solid green;
    }
   th
  {
      background-color:green;
      color:white;
  }
</style>
```